# Pig Script error while using SUM()

Tags: apache-pig

I get the following error while running this PIG Script....Please Help!!!
Thanks in advance.

```
"ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Scalars can be only used with projections"

MOVIES = LOAD '/MOVIES' using PigStorage(',') as (mid:double, mn:chararray, yr:int, rt:float, dr:int);

Filter11 = filter MOVIES by $2 >= 1950;

Filter12 = filter Filter11 by $2 <= 1960;

Group1 = group Filter12 by yr;

Count1 = foreach Group1 generate group, COUNT(Filter12);

Sum1 = foreach Count1 generate SUM(Group1);

DUMP Sum1;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The SUM function needs to be performed on one of the columns that are defined in MOVIES  .

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two filter conditions and in the last step, sum the counts i.e. COUNT(Filter11) or $1.

```
MOVIES = LOAD '/MOVIES' using PigStorage(',') as (mid:double, mn:chararray, yr:int, rt:float, dr:int);
Filter11 = filter MOVIES by ($2 >= 1950 and $2 <= 1960);
Group1 = group Filter11 by yr;
Count1 = foreach Group1 generate group, COUNT(Filter11);
Sum1 = foreach Count1 generate SUM($1);
DUMP Sum1;
```